# How to change multiple file names in C#?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have file names that contain numbers that need to be decremented by 1. I need code that satisfies the following pseudocode:

```
class ReplaceSubstrings
    {
        string searchFor;
        string replaceWith;
        Bool filenamecontainnumbers; 'file name contains numbers to be       decremented by 1
        int filenamenumbers; ' file name size varies from 10 to 500 - I only want to          ' target integers 200 - 500

    while(filenamecontainsnumbers = 1) ' maybe I should use Bool condition

    ReplaceSubstrings app = new ReplaceSubstrings();
    If(filenamenumbers > 200){
        app.searchFor = filenamenumbers; // A very simple regular expression.
        app.replaceWith = decnamenumber();
        Console.WriteLine(s);

    return 0; 

}


void decnamenumber(){

filenamenumbers = filenamenumbers - 1;

 };
```

or something like this!!! Help Please!!!

Comment: This looks like the jumbled mess of a school assignment done by a first year student who hasn't been paying attention at all.

Comment: School Assigments should be done by the student. Try do the assigment first, and if you have any questions, we can help you with that. But no one will do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

for "renaming" in c# you can just "move" the file: check out this http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-move